# ReactJS Onclick function not working with href

Tags: javascript, reactjs

`href` is not working when I click the `<a>` element with an `onClick` function with it

```
function Sidebar() {

    function toggleChange(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const el = document.getElementById("dashboard-button");
    el.className="nav-link";

    }
    return(
                    <div>
                      <li className="nav-item active">
                        <a className='nav-link collapsed' id="dashboard-button" 
                         href='./dashboardpage' onClick={toggleChange}>
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-table-columns"></i>
                        <span>Dashboard</span>
                        </a>
                        </li>
                       </div>
         )
}
```

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` prevents default behaviour.

Comment: you might want to consider using a routing lib like `react-router` etc., ..

Answer (score 0):

You need to add in toggleChange function history.push('/dashboardpage');
For more detail
https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory

Otherwise you can remove e.preventDefault();

Answer (score 0):

You can use `e.preventDefault()`
The preventDefault() method cancels the event if it is cancelable, meaning that the default action that belongs to the event will not occur.

For example, this can be useful when: Clicking on a "Submit" button, prevent it from submitting a form. Clicking on a link, prevent the link from following the URL.